# MVC input DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I use EditFor in MVC my DateTime field show a not formated datetime, If I use a old school html my field don't receive the error class.

```
<div class="editor-field">
     <input type="text" name="EstimateTime" id="EstimateTime" value="<%: (Model != null) ? Model.EstimateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") : "" %>" />
     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EstimateTime, new { @value = (Model != null) ? Model.EstimateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") : "" })%>
     <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstimateTime) %>
</div>
```

result HTML: *Look the difference between the value:*

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input type="text" name="EstimateTime" id="EstimateTime" value="31/10/2013 01:54:42 PM" class="hasDatepicker">
    <input  id="EstimateTime" name="EstimateTime" type="text" value="10/31/2013 1:54:42 PM" class="input-validation-error text-box single-line">
    <span class="field-validation-error">Isn't a date/time valid</span>
</div>
```

What is the best practices to fix it?

Comment: It swapped the day for the month. What's the big deal?

Comment: the problem is, if I use Model.EstimateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") the date are show formated MM/dd/.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public System.DateTime EstimateTime { get; set; }
```

This is working for me in the latest version of Chrome

Comment: I don't think chrome has any relation to it.

Answer (score 2):

Add `DataFormatString` to the property in your model.

```
public class YourModel
{
   [DisplayName("Estimate Time:"), 
    DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}")]
   public System.DateTime EstimateTime { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Comment: You should also probably specify `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` in the `DisplayFormat` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I always use an Editor Template to perfect output control

this is DateTime.cshtml:

```
@model System.DateTime?

@{
    IDictionary<string, object> Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    if (ViewData.ContainsKey("style")) {
        Attributes.Add("style", (string)ViewData["style"]);
    }
    if (ViewData.ContainsKey("autohelp")) {
        Attributes.Add("title", (string)ViewData["autohelp"]);
    }
    if (ViewData.ContainsKey("autofocus")) {
        Attributes.Add("autofocus", (string)ViewData["autofocus"]);
    }
    Attributes.Add("class", "fecha");
    Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
}


@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), Attributes)
```