# How to implement a calendar in ASP.net that when a date is picked, and it returns the stored data for the chosen date?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

[![*emphasized text*][1]][1]

Right now, I have an input box on the left which is a drop down calendar and a button called "download log" which actually dl's the logged file. I wanted to have a logic that when I choose a certain date in the calendar per se, yesterday's log it will dl that log. I have the code for the down load log, but still couldn't figure out on what to do about the calendar.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jGrh.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698085/mvc-input-datetime

Comment: https://youtu.be/dsk4YyDEn4w